# How to make Laravel 4 application with "read only" database mode

Tags: php, laravel, event-handling

I'd like to make my Laravel 4 application have a read only mode. So any updates/writes to the database would be ignored.

Is the correct way to do this to listen on the eloquent* events and return false?

Answer (score 0):

Listening on the events and returning false wouldn't work -- Laravel's events are only notifications, they don't control the actions themselves. i.e. you're listening for a shout, but you can't stop the shout from happening.  Returning false from an event only stops other listeners that fire after your listener.

Re: a "read only" mode, a lot would depend on how your application is writing to the database, but I'd start by rewriting the `DB` facade to rewrite your own object (that extends the original database object), and then redefines any insert/update/etc. method to do nothing if the site was in read only mode.  You'll want to make sure these methods still return something like they would normally (array, empty DB resource, etc).

**Update** It's worth noting, that some components (like Eloquent) will use a `return false` from an event to signal that certain events should not happen.

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();

    // If the "saving" event returns false we'll bail out of the save and return
    // false, indicating that the save failed. This gives an opportunities to
    // listeners to cancel save operations if validations fail or whatever.
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('saving') === false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //... rest of save code here
```

The `fireModelEvent` method is what fires the event -- if it returns false then Eloquent will not perform the save.  This is what I meant by *a lot would depend on how your application is writing to the database* -- the event behavior described above is a choice the Eloquent develops made -- not all events will behave in that way, and not all operations that add/remove data from the database will fire events.

Comment: I tried Event::listen('eloquent.*',function( $model){...}); though, just returning false, and writes do stop happening. So it appears to work.

Comment: @jimbo2087 Updated my answer to clarify (also -- I didn't know that Eloquent did that, thanks!)